# How to reset the sshd_config file to its default settings

Tags: configuration, sshd, macintosh, ssh-config

I have changed some stuff within the sshd_config file and want to reset the file to its default settings. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ssh default config file is on `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you can copy it to `.ssh` directory by the following command

```
sudo cp /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config ~/.ssh/config
```

Then restart SSHD:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

Comment: Beware. There are 2 configuration files for ssh : `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which is the configuration for the **client** SSH, and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which the configuration for the **server** SSH.

Answer (score 2):

If it is for MAC i found this it may be useful

https://gist.github.com/n8felton/91e71a7c64f9f05ed6a5467f9164bb7e

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver. I have been looking everywhere, well almost everywhere, lol